# How can download the resource whose url contains special characters "#!"?

Tags: yt-dlp

I want to download the resource whose url contains special characters "#!" ?

```
yt-dlp  "https://d.tube/#!/v/mes/jjyzkes4zes"
bash: !/v/mes/jjyzkes4zes: event not found
```

Use single quote:

```
yt-dlp  'https://d.tube/#!/v/mes/jjyzkes4zes'
[DTube] Extracting URL: https://d.tube/#!/v/mes/jjyzkes4zes
[DTube] jjyzkes4: Downloading JSON metadata
ERROR: jjyzkes4: An extractor error has occurred. (caused by KeyError('result')); please report this issue on  https://github.com/yt-dlp/yt-dlp/issues?q= , filling out the appropriate issue template. Confirm you are on the latest version using  yt-dlp -U
```

Comment: try single quotes: `yt-dlp  'https://d.tube/#!/v/mes/jjyzkes4zes'`

Comment: The part after `#` is the fragment, it is not sent to the server, it looks like the server can't identify the video. But the “share” option on this website gives this link: `https://d.tube/v/mes/jjyzkes4zes`, so try `yt-dlp "https://d.tube/v/mes/jjyzkes4zes"`.